# Writing an R loop to create new standardized columns

Tags: r, loops

I'm using the Ionosphere dataset in R and am trying to write a loop that will create new columns that are standardized iterations of existing columns and name them accordingly.

I've got the "cname" as the new column name and c as the original. The code is:

```
install.packages("mlbench") 
library(mlbench) 
data('Ionosphere')
library(robustHD)
col <- colnames(Ionosphere)
for (c in col[1:length(col)-1]){
  cname <- paste(c,"Std")
  Ionosphere$cname <- standardize(Ionosphere$c)

  }
```

But get the following error:

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cname", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 351
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"
```

I feel like there's something super-simple I'm missing but I just can't see it.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: It is usually good practice to avoid naming objects with common function names, such as `c` (as in `c()`). Are you sure there is a variable called "c"?

Comment: Please share this "Ionosphere" data. You can use `dput(head(Ionosphere, 10))`

Comment: c is basically the loop. It loops over every column name then (in theory) creates a new column with the original column name + std.

Comment: What's `data_set`?

Comment: Sorry, data_set shouldnt be there. was trying different things. I've edited it now.

Comment: V1 V2      V3       V4      V5      V6      V7       V8 V9    V10     V11      V12     V13      V14     V15      V16     V17      V18     V19      V20     V21      V22     V23
1  1  0 0.99539 -0.05889 0.85243 0.02306 0.83398 -0.37708  1 0.0376 0.85243 -0.17755 0.59755 -0.44945 0.60536 -0.38223 0.84356 -0.38542 0.58212 -0.32192 0.56971 -0.29674 0.36946
       V24     V25      V26     V27      V28     V29     V30     V31      V32     V33    V34 Class
1 -0.47357 0.56811 -0.51171 0.41078 -0.46168 0.21266 -0.3409 0.42267 -0.54487 0.18641 -0.453     1

Comment: Please always share the data inside the question, not in comments. You can edit the question. And please ALWAYS use dput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply`, a custom-made standardization function, setNames, and cbind.
I do not have access to your dataset, so I am using the iris dataset as an example:

```
df<-iris
cbind(df, set_names(lapply(df[1:4],
                           \(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)),
                     paste0(names(df[1:4]), '_Std')))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Sepal.Length_Std Sepal.Width_Std Petal.Length_Std Petal.Width_Std
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa      -0.89767388      1.01560199      -1.33575163   -1.3110521482
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa      -1.13920048     -0.13153881      -1.33575163   -1.3110521482
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa      -1.38072709      0.32731751      -1.39239929   -1.3110521482
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa      -1.50149039      0.09788935      -1.27910398   -1.3110521482
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa      -1.01843718      1.24503015      -1.33575163   -1.3110521482
...
```

I feel these transformations get easier with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                       ~ (.x - mean(.x))/sd(.x),
                       .names = "{col}_Std"))
```